# Pausing/resuming multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, resume, suspend

Trying to write a program that will run, suspend, and resume 3 threads.

here's the coding:

```
class Connectthread implements Runnable
{
public void run()
{
    for(int j=0;j<90;j+=10)
    System.out.println("Connecting..." + j + " Secs");
}
}

class DLoadthread implements Runnable
{
public void run()
{
    for(int d=0;d<60;d+=10)
    System.out.println("Downloading..." + d + " Secs");
}
}
class Runthread implements Runnable
{
public void run()
{
    for(int r=0;r<120;r+=10)
    System.out.println("Running..." + r + " Secs");
}
}
class EHAunitThread
{
Connectthread ct=new Connectthread();
DLoadthread dt=new DLoadthread();
Runthread rt=new Runthread();

public void main(String arg[])
{
    //putting threads into ready state.
    System.out.print("Starting threads\n");
    ct.start();
    dt.start();
    rt.start();

    System.out.print("Sleeping 3 seconds\n");
    safeSleep(3000, "Threads first sleep time interrupted\n");
    System.out.print("Suspending threads\n");
    ct.suspend();
    dt.suspend();
    rt.suspend();

    System.out.print("Sleep 5 seconds\n");
    safeSleep(5000, "Threads second sleep time interrupted\n");
    System.out.print("Resume threads\n");
    ct.resume();
    dt.resume();
    rt.resume();

    try
    {
        ct.join();
        dt.join();
        rt.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.print("Join interrupted");
    }

    System.out.print("Testcase Completed");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

it keeps giving me 14 of these `error:cannot find symbol` messages when i try to compile it.

To my knowledge, the coding *looks* correct as far as grammar is concerned. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The compiler also displays the missing `symbol:` and a nice excerpt intended to help you find out what exactly it's missing.

Comment: The threads will all be finished when you'll try to suspend them. And as the compiler and the javadoc tells you: `suspend()` and `resume()` are deprecated and should thus **not** be used. Don't use `suspend()` and `resume()`. BTW, I don't won't to be rude, but if you don't know how to fix such a basic compilation issue, you're not ready to mess with threads, which are a very, very, **very** complex matter.

Comment: @ignis: it doesn't say anything about what's missing.

Comment: @JBNizet: Im just starting to study java, so I don't really know very well how to interpret some of the error messages the compiler gives me. and ik im not ready to mess w/ threads yet, but this is for school so i dont really have a choice.

Comment: Does your teach ask you to use suspend() and resume()? It's already a bad choice to make you learn threads at the very beginning of a Java course, but asking to use methods which are deprecated for years because they're dangerous to use is plain stupid. Don't tell him that, but gently ask why he asks you to use these methods, sicne they're documented as deprecated and dangerous.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. Ended up just making it look like it suspended/resumed the threads, because thats really all the assignment was asking me to do anyways. Didn't really use much of what any of you said in this case, but it will definitely help for future projects.

Comment: Im in an online course, which isn't ideal, so there's not as much teacher-student interaction as brick and mortar.  All I really have to work with unless I set up an Eluminate session is the stuff in the lesson and google.  The stuff in the lesson was probably written about 8 years ago, because most of the screenshots were taken from a comp that is/was running XP. And google isn't always helpful because its sometimes hard to know exactly what I'm even looking for.

Comment: @Jeremy: 'symbol' means 'a method, variable, class, interface, or field'. My javac prints out `cannot find symbol: method join(); location: variable dt of type DLoadthread`.

Comment: Right. but what I'm not sure about is how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspend and resume() are unsafe try this aprocach:

```
public class Pauser{

  private boolean isPaused=false;

  public synchronized void pause(){
     isPaused=true;
    }

  public synchronized void resume(){
    isPaused=false;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized void look(){
    while(isPaused){
        wait();
      }
   }

}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

  Pauser pauser;

  public MyRunnable(Pauser pauser){
     this.pauser=pauser;
   }

  public void run(){
    while(true){
       pauser.look();
    }
  }

public class Caller{

  Pauser pauser=new Pauser();
  for(int i = 0; i<1000;i++)
    new Thread(new MyRunnable(pauser)).start();

//pause all threads
pauser.pause();

//resume all threads
pauser.resume();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your classes are Runnables and you call Thread methods on them. You need to wrap them in Thread objects:

```
Thread ct=new Thread (newConnectthread());
```

Also note that [Thread#suspend()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29) is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up just making it look like it suspended/resumed the threads because thats really all the assignment was asking me to do. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`Runnable` has no `start` method. You need to use the `Thread` class to encapsulate the `Runnable`s:

```
Thread ct = new Thread(new Connectthread());
Thread dt = new Thread(new DLoadthread());
Thread rt = new Thread(new Runthread());
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up just making it look like it suspended/resumed the threads, because thats really all the assignment was asking me to do anyways.